# First occurrence of $scope.email is not showing

Tags: angularjs

I have an `AuthenticationController` in a `<div>`. I am trying to print `{{ email }}` twice, but it only shows up the second time.

```
<div class="login" ng-controller="AuthenticationController">
    <!-- This DOESN'T show -->
    {{ email }}

    <div ng-switch on="isLoggedIn()">

        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <input ng-click="logout()" type="submit" value="Logout">
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="false">
            <!-- This IS shown -->
            {{ email }}

            <input ng-model="email" type="text">
            <input ng-model="password" type="password">
            <input ng-click="login()" type="submit" value="Login">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Why is the first `{{ email }}` not printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngSwitch` creates a new scope. Try using an object:

```
<div class="login" ng-controller="AuthenticationController">    
    {{user.email}}
    <div ng-switch on="isLoggedIn()">
        ...
        ... 
        <input ng-model="user.email" type="text">
```

#### Controller:

```
$scope.user = {
    email:""
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same result